# addListener in a for loop does not work right

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good evening,

I used the Google Maps API to add dynamically (for loop) 5 markers and infoboxes to a map. Now I want to set the listeners dynamically, I got the following code:

```
for(var i in partnerschools){
            infoContent = 'BLABLA';
            info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: infoContent,
                maxWidth: 230
            });
            infos.push(info);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: partnerschools[i].coordinates,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: partnerschools[i].title,
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            markers[i].addListener('click', function(){
                infos[i].open(map, markers[i]);
            });
        }
```

The problem is that its always the same infobox that opens after clicking on one of these markers. Everything works really good until I try to add listeners to every marker, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: Use this link, I answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32922108/3518319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
var addListener = function (i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
        infos[i].open(map, markers[i]);                 
    });
}
addListener(i);
```